# PostgreSQL - Insert fails n times for n already inserted rows - reset autoincrement

Tags: mysql, postgresql, auto-increment

For setting up our workbench application we got some db-seed files to populate our postgres-database. One of those files inserts permission-references into the `workbench_group_permissions_reference` table:

```
INSERT INTO workbench_group_permissions_reference(id, workbench_groups_id, workbenchgroupspermissions_id)
VALUES 
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 4),
(5, 1, 5),
(6, 1, 6),
(7, 1, 7),
(8, 1, 8),
(9, 1, 9),
(10, 1, 10),
(11, 1, 11),
(12, 1, 12),
(13, 1, 13),
(14, 1, 14),
(15, 1, 15);
```

The problem is that the auto-increment counter is still at `0` after running this script & new inserts fail with an `Duplicate identifier`-Error.

Is there any way I can update the auto-increment counter after my script did run?

Comment: Use [setval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) after your script.

Comment: or `alter sequence restart with`

Comment: why field is the auto increment counter? and why are you passing in a value for it instead of letting it auto generate?  If you override an autogen w/ a vale it takes your value.  so don't pass one in.